Process Memory Usage in C on Windows
I want record the memory usage of my program. Here is a example.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

void getMemInfo(){
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *)&pmc, sizeof(pmc));
    SIZE_T virtualMemUsedByMe = pmc.PrivateUsage;
    SIZE_T physMemUsedByMe = pmc.WorkingSetSize;
    printf("%ld, %ld\n", virtualMemUsedByMe, physMemUsedByMe);
}
int main()
{
    double a[1000];
    
    getMemInfo();
    double *b = malloc(sizeof(double)*1000);
    
    getMemInfo();
    free(b);

    getMemInfo();
    return 0;
}

I compile it and run it three times;

Well. Now I have few questions.

Why does the usage of my program [or my program output] change every time? Did I use the wrong parameters of pmc?
How to record the memory usage of c program in time before and after allocating new memory?
I want to optimize a c project. So I should use which parameter of pmc as a benchmark？

Refer:

Collecting Memory Usage Information For a Process
c++ - How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process - Stack Overflow


I am surprized that it has changed after malloc you did not touch the allocated memory

Yes. I thought it will output the same result with the same exe.

could be nothing more than memory alignment for each instantiation as the heap and actual location of memory will likely differ each time

fyi, running something similar on linux host, VM stays at one val (2492k), but physical mem varies between 504kb and 584kb - over 50000 iterations ....just sayin

I think you're right. I will post my conclusion later.

I think you allocated a very small size in double *b;
allocate uses memory in the heap.
So your process already have some free heap size. To see the change in process memory usage, you must allocate space more than the current heap size minute the free heap size.
Try:
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "psapi.lib" )
#include <malloc.h>

long HeapUsed()
{
_HEAPINFO info = { 0, 0, 0 };
long used = 0;
int rc;

while ((rc=_heapwalk(&info)) == _HEAPOK)
{
    if (info._useflag == _USEDENTRY)
        used += info._size;
}
if (rc != _HEAPEND && rc != _HEAPEMPTY)
    used = (used?-used:-1);

return used;
}


unsigned long GetHeapInitializedSize(HANDLE heap)
{
unsigned long sz = 0;
HeapLock(heap);
PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY entry;
memset(&entry, '\0', sizeof entry);
while (HeapWalk(heap, &entry))
{
    if (entry.wFlags != PROCESS_HEAP_UNCOMMITTED_RANGE)
    {
        sz += entry.cbData + entry.cbOverhead;
    }
}
HeapUnlock(heap);
return sz;
}
#include <intsafe.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

DWORD NumberOfHeaps;
HRESULT Result;
PHANDLE aHeaps;
SIZE_T BytesToAllocate;
HANDLE hDefaultProcessHeap;
long heap_size;
DWORD processID;
HANDLE hProcess;
long heap_used_size;
long heap_free_size;
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
NumberOfHeaps = GetProcessHeaps(0, NULL);
Result = SIZETMult(NumberOfHeaps, sizeof(*aHeaps), &BytesToAllocate);
hDefaultProcessHeap = GetProcessHeap();
heap_size = GetHeapInitializedSize(hDefaultProcessHeap);
processID =  GetProcessId(GetCurrentProcess());
hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID );
heap_used_size = HeapUsed();



char *b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(heap_size - heap_used_size + 1024));
if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(  hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)))
{
    printf( "\tWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X - %u\n",  pmc.WorkingSetSize,  
        pmc.WorkingSetSize / 1024);        
    printf( "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", 
        pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage ,   pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage, 
        pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", 
        pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage,pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage / 1024 );
    printf( "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage:0x%08X-%u\n",pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage ,   pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.PagefileUsage,     pmc.PagefileUsage/1024 ); 
    printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.PeakPagefileUsage, pmc.PeakPagefileUsage/1024 );
    printf( "\tcb: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.cb , pmc.cb / 1024);     
}

free(b);
if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(  hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)))
{
    printf( "\tWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X - %u\n",  pmc.WorkingSetSize,  
        pmc.WorkingSetSize / 1024);        
    printf( "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", 
        pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage ,   pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage, 
        pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", 
        pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage,pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage / 1024 );
    printf( "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage:0x%08X-%u\n",pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage ,   pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage / 1024);
    printf( "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.PagefileUsage,     pmc.PagefileUsage/1024 ); 
    printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.PeakPagefileUsage, pmc.PeakPagefileUsage/1024 );
    printf( "\tcb: 0x%08X - %u\n", pmc.cb , pmc.cb / 1024);     
}


Why does the usage of my program [or my program output] change every time? Did I use the wrong parameters of pmc?

That’s because you use printf. Try this:
SIZE_T arr[5][2];
int cur_index = 0;

void getMemInfo(){
     PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
     SIZE_T virtualMemUsedByMe;
     SIZE_T physMemUsedByMe;
     GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), 
(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *)&pmc, sizeof(pmc));
virtualMemUsedByMe = pmc.PrivateUsage;
physMemUsedByMe = pmc.WorkingSetSize;
arr[cur_index][0] = virtualMemUsedByMe;
arr[cur_index][1] = physMemUsedByMe;
cur_index++;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   for(int u = 0; u < 5; u++) {
      getMemInfo();
      Sleep(1000);
   }

    for(int u = 0; u < 5; u++) 
      fprintf(stdout,"%ld, %ld\n", arr[u][0], arr[u][1]);

I got
860160, 4681728
860160, 4681728
860160, 4681728
860160, 4681728
860160, 4681728

